# Rails: Create comment validation paths (accept or reject)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, comments

In my app, users can write reviews for products. But before publishing the review, the admin needs to accept the review or reject it (allowing the user to change its review).

To manage the validation part, I created the `validate` method inside the `Reviews` controller. The admin has two buttons (links) near the new review: Accep, Reject. That buttons redirect to the `validate#reviews` and send the appropriate parameters: `review_id` and `admin_action` (accept or reject).

**How do I create the path of the buttons (links)?**

I tried many combinations like `link_to "accept", polymorphic_path([review, :validate => 'accep'])` but without success. *I have trouble to figure out how the URL should look like!* Of course, I added `get 'reviews/validate'` to routes.rb before.

If you had in a similar situation, how did you do? Is there best practices?

**Update**

I also tried `link_to "Accept", polymorphic_path(:reviews => review, :validate => 'accept')`, but get a *Nil location provided. Can't build URI*.

**Update 2**

I would like to use the `validate` method (instead of creating two methods `accept` and `reject`) because there are common data processing, like getting the review, checking admin auth,...

So, in my controller, I'm looking for something like:

```
def activate
    # Get review, using review_id

    # Check in the admin has the right to validate the review

    # Execute the correct action: accept or reject.
end

private
def accept
    ...
end

def reject
    ...
end
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your routes.rb:

```
resources :reviews do
  member do
    put :accept
    put :reject
  end
end
```

This will make the urls reviews/:id/accept and reviews/:id reject available through the helpers accept_review_path(@review) and reject_review_path(@review).

Last thing, in your ReviewsController add

```
def accept
  @review = Review.find(params[:id])
  # Your accept logic here
end

def reject
  @review = Review.find(params[:id])
  # Your reject logic here
end
```

Comment: Excellent Erez and thanks, it's the kind of solution I was looking for. I just need to take one more step, because `accept` and `reject` methods should be private. My only entry point is teh `validate` method that perform testing (like checking authorisation) and then execute the correct action. Please, see bellow my second update.

Comment: I finally get it: Just use `link_to "Accept", validate_review_path(review, :type => "accept")` as a link, and in the controller, redirect to the correct action using `if params[:type] == 'accept' ...`. Thanks a lot, Erez.

Answer (score 0):

You just add a new **review** get method as member for **validate** controller. Then give find the path of this action by giving command **rake routes**. Then give that path to your button with a parameter. The parameter should be 1 .  accept, 2 . reject.

Comment: Is it really necassary to create a new controller `validate`? I just wanted `validate` to be a method of `Review` in order to not have too many controllers. Is it possible to do it like this?

Comment: You said redirect to "validate#reviews", so that only i said validate controller. I think you have reviews controller, so create a new member action "validate" for reviews controller. Then use this path in your accetp, reject button's link. Provide the parameter as accept or reject based on your buttons.